# Why is there a random text arrow in my app?

Tags: angular

I have a text arrow (exactly this: -->) in the top left corner of my app and I don't know why. It is visible on only some of the routes. Does somebody know why is there?
Here is a pic of the source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tpr2U.jpg

Comment: is it a closing comment tag that is extra?

Comment: ? It’s clearly there under app-appointment... so probablt just an end-comment you forgot to delete.

Comment: Please share any html code of your app, index.html and any component html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have this in your component.

You had commented your component and then wrongly uncommented.

Then it left: `-->`

This is some commmented HTML :

```
<!-- </comment-tree> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I previously commented out a line and I left there that.